# flutter blue example can't connect to gatt server

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to create an application (on flutter/android studio) that can connect to a Ble server and read his characteristics. I used the flutter_blue_example : https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/tree/master/example .

The scan goes fine, but when I try to connect to the BLE device it does'nt work and I get the following log on android studio :

```
D/BluetoothGatt( 8205): onClientConnectionState() - status=133 clientIf=8 
device=00:1A:7D:DA:71:13
D/FlutterBluePlugin( 8205): onConnectionStateChange: 
D/BluetoothGatt( 8205): close()
D/BluetoothGatt( 8205): unregisterApp() - mClientIf=8
```

I used the following example to create my Ble server : https://github.com/Jumperr-labs/python-gatt-server

The problem could come from the server but as it works good with an app like Ble scanner available on the playstore, I think the problem is more likely to come from the app based on flutter.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that I had to pair with the device in the bluetooth parameters before launching my app. BTW there are still issues with the refresh of the discovered services, but I am working on it.

Comment: i'm trying flutter_blue example code. Bluetooth scanning is ok but not getting any advertisementData, All fields are null

Comment: I encounter the same issue using the flutter_blue example code on android to connect to the example Microsoft BluetoothLE-app on Windows 10. Flutter discovers the UWP app but cannot connect somehow. Yet, I use LightBlue app on Android that can connect to the UWP app and discover services. So Lightblue doesn't need pairing to retrieve services. Then why would flutter_blue need pairing first to obtain the service id's?